# Can't delete keychain items with UI, but command line works fine

Tags: command-line, security, keychain

When using the `Keychain Access` app, I am often unable to delete an `Web form password` item. I have tried hitting the `delete` key and going to `Edit` > `Delete`. In both cases, nothing happens, there is no error message.

I can delete the item if I use the command line version of the tool:

```
$ security find-internet-password -a "foo@example.com"
keychain: "/Users/simon/Library/Keychains/woodside-mbp.keychain"
version: 256
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="daw.apple.com (foo@example.com)"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>="foo@example.com"
    "atyp"<blob>="form"
    ...
$ security delete-internet-password -a "foo@example.com"
keychain: "/Users/simon/Library/Keychains/woodside-mbp.keychain"
version: 256
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="daw.apple.com (foo@example.com)"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>="foo@example.com"
    "atyp"<blob>="form"
    ...
password has been deleted.
```

If I now redo the search in Keychain Access, the item is gone.

I am running El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65), Keychain Access Version 9.0 (55171.20.2), and

Comment: In the Keychain Access application, does the keychain you are trying to delete from (e.g., login, Local Items, or System) show a locked padlock icon next to it? If so, try clicking the padlock icon in the upper-left corner, entering your password, then trying to delete it again.

Comment: @PseudoSu: the keychain is unlocked.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I notice you say, "If I now redo the search in Keychain Access…" implying that you began by searching when you weren't able to delete the item. Find it in the list without searching and then delete. It's just a dumb bug. I have found I sometimes can delete a single item after searching, but not multiple, and sometimes there's no problem at all. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I cannot believe this crap. Unbelievable. It just works, they say. THANKS!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: oh my god, i was getting ready to call IT helpdesk

Comment: This answer still holds true on Big Sur 11.4!

Comment: Once I delete an item using this method (selecting without a search), it seems like I can afterwards delete while searching.

Comment: the dumbest bug indeed. come on it's 2021!

Comment: I've found that @karmstr7 is right in a different answer: You can delete an item in the search results, but only if you have the correct keychain selected in the left sidebar (the keychain the item actually is stored it, which is listed in a column in the search results).

Comment: Also still true in Monterey 12.5

Comment: One of the richest tech companies in the world should not have a bug persist for years that I would not have as a newbie messing around with Windows programming and Borland C++ builder in 2002.

Comment: This bug is still in macOS 13.0.1.

Comment: @Apple MacOS please fix this. Still valid as of today

Comment: Ventura 13.3 still exhibits this issue

Comment: Venture 13.4 is still rocking this bug.  Deletion of multiple search results across multiple keychains is particularly tedious; the workaround is to delete per-keychain, with the keychain selected in the left hand pane.

Comment: Have reported the bug to Apple via Feedback Assistant.

Answer (score 45):

Had the same problem, found that I was able to delete keys once I switched from `iCloud` to `login` in the `Default Keychains` section.

Comment: yeah, strange Mac UI!

Comment: This works for me on Ventura 13.0

Comment: Thank you. This works for me on Monterey 12.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

If the password entry was created while using safari, you will need to delete it in the preferences of safari rather then through the keychain. The entry will be found under the password tab in preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete the key from the Keychain Access application from the **Default Keychains** > **iCloud**. The full action is:

1. Open the "Keychain Access" application
2. Click the **iCloud** entry in the left panel under **Default Keychains**
3. Search for your key through the search bar
4. Chose your item and right-click, then click the **Delete** option

Comment: Thank you. This works for me on Monterey 12.6.2.